# java.lang.AssertionError: No value at JSON path "name"

Tags: spring, testing

> java.lang.AssertionError: No value at JSON path "name"    at
> org.springframework.test.util.JsonPathExpectationsHelper.evaluateJsonPath(JsonPathExpectationsHelper.java:304)
> at
> org.springframework.test.util.JsonPathExpectationsHelper.assertValue(JsonPathExpectationsHelper.java:99)
> at
> org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.JsonPathResultMatchers.lambda$value$2(JsonPathResultMatchers.java:111)
> at
> org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc$1.andExpect(MockMvc.java:212)
> at
> com.nix.tdd.CarControllerTest.getCar_ShouldRetuenCar(CarControllerTest.java:29)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
> org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
> at
> org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
> at
> org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
> at
> org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
> at
> org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:74)
> at
> org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:84)
> at
> org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
> at
> org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
> at
> org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)    at
> org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
> at
> org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)  at
> org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)   at
> org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)     at
> org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)   at
> org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)  at
> org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
> at
> org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)

Below is the complete set of code.

```
package com.nix.tdd;
  
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.get;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.content;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTest;
 
import org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplate;
 
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
  
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(CarController.class)
public class CarControllerTest {
    
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;
  
    @Test
    public void getCar_ShouldRetuenCar() throws Exception{  
      this.mockMvc.perform(get("/cars/dezire"))
          .andExpect(status().isOk())
          .andExpect(jsonPath("name").value("dezire"))
          .andExpect(jsonPath("type").value("diesel"));
    }
 }
```

---

```
package com.nix.tdd;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class TddApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TddApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

---

```
package com.nix.tdd;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.nix.tdd.domain.Car;

@RestController
public class CarController {

    @GetMapping("/cars/{name}")
    private Car getCar(@PathVariable String name) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.nix.tdd</groupId>
    <artifactId>TDD</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>TDD</name>
    <description>LoginJJWT</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: You're returning `null` from the `Controller`, and asserting on the value (specifically, at json path `$.name`).  There isn't a value there because you returned `null`.

Comment: Thanks , Well you are right.  It works after returning the Car object.    @GetMapping("/cars/{name}")
 private Car getCar(@PathVariable String name) {
  Car car=new Car("dezire","diesel");
  return car;
 }